# Git commit-msg exec npm test

Tags: githooks

I'd like to verify my commit message using git hook and exec `npm test`.

For the commit message everythink works but it seems not working for `npm test` if the test fail.

**Commit message that I want to accept :**

```
[FIX-A1325] KEYWORDS : Word1 word2
[FIX-D1325-P4556] KEYWORDS : Word1 word2
[NEW] KEYWORD : Word1 word2
[UPD] KEYWORD : Word1 word2
[DOC] Word1 word2
TMP
[REF] KEYWORD : Word1 word2
[GIT] Word1 word2
[DEL] Word1 word2
```

**My code :**

```
#!/bin/sh

commitMessage=$(cat $1)

pattern="TMP|\[FIX-A[0-9]+\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[FIX-D[0-9]+-P[0-9]+\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[NEW\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[REF\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[DOC\]\s.+|\[UPD\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[GIT\]\s.+|\[DEL\]\s.+"

if [[ ! "$commitMessage" =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "Commit message invalid => $commitMessage"
    exit 1
fi

npm test
```

Comment: you probably want to add `set -e` to your script.  also you probably don't want to run `npm test` during `commit-msg` but instead during `pre-commit` (since the staged contents may not be set yet)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to catch the exit code of `npm test` and exit your script with it like:

```
#!/bin/sh

commitMessage=$(cat $1)

pattern="TMP|\[FIX-A[0-9]+\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[FIX-D[0-9]+-P[0-9]+\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[NEW\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[REF\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[DOC\]\s.+|\[UPD\]\s[A-Z]+\s:\s.+|\[GIT\]\s.+|\[DEL\]\s.+"

if [[ ! "$commitMessage" =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "Commit message invalid => $commitMessage"
    exit 1
fi


npm test

# $? stores exit value of the last command
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
 echo "Tests must pass before commit!"
 exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but it seems that I get an issue with the pattern because all my commit message are rejected. Do you know if I forget something in the pattern ?

Comment: You can see an edit in my post.